# Level of Detail algorithm(s) and texture coordinates

Tags: level-of-detail

I'm playing with LOD these days and trying a couple of implementations, specifically quadric mesh simplification, there is a [link](http://voxels.blogspot.gr/2014/05/quadric-mesh-simplification-with-source.html?showComment=1452819241628#c6162336080937496439).

I don't have problem simplifying my models but i do have problem finding the correct texture coordinates after simplification. *None* of the implementations i found (many) cover texturing, they only handle flat colored triangles, and i was wondering if it's possible anyhow to preserve coordinates.

Is there an approach to handle texture coordinates on quadric simplified meshes?
I tried storing the original texture coordinates into their faces before passing them to simplifier, then restore them but the results are clearly wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is usually these mesh simplifications are done before texturing.

Then the reduced mesh is UV unwrapped.

And finally using the original mesh as the source, the materials are baked into the target textures by raycasting from the reduced mesh into the original mesh to figure out the color maps and normal map.

A completely new texture and UV set is generated for the reduced mesh.

Comment: Thanx for clarifying this. Do you have any source link for the raycasting method to rebuild my coordinates, is there an approach or i have to use some software?

Comment: That's usually done in the 3D editor with the texture baking tool.